# How bitcoin tax is calculated?

Tags: buy-bitcoins, taxes

I bought 1 bitcoin and sold part of it to make cash from time to time. How will tax on this income be calculated?

Comment: sorry, can't resist: in case there are taxes to be paid, with the current plunging of prices, it will reduce your load :-) Maybe you want to add another tag like "tax"...

Comment: thank you:) what do you mean reduce load?

Comment: You would have to pay less... I searched the forum for tax, but couldn’t make up my mind. Complicated matter!

Comment: How can we know the tax laws in your country, when you haven't even told us what country you are in?  You may also want to browse the [tag:taxes] tag since we have a lot of other questions on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I’ll start this off by saying I’m not a tax professional, so take this advice as you will...

At the time you purchase your bitcoin, your purchase price becomes your cost basis. This means if you bought 1 bitcoin for $10,000 then this is the price you will compare your capital gain/losses to.

For example let’s say you buy 1 bitcoin at $10,000. A week later the price of 1 bitcoin is $12,000. You decide to sell half your bitcoin due to the price hike and you receive $6,000 for the sale. Your tax liability would be $1,000 in capital gains (sale price of half a bitcoin is $6,000 minus original price of half a bitcoin is $5,000). I believe the in the US the tax on short term capital gains is whatever income tax bracket you fall into, so you would pay a X% capital gain tax on the $1000 profit you made from selling half your bitcoin.

Again I’m not a tax professional, but this is my understanding of how it all works based on lots of research.

Comment: @NateEldredge is right, my mistake. The answer has been updated to reflect his added information

Comment: In Australia it is very similar but it varies for each country or region.